# Create an Ad-Hoc Wireless Network

Tags: networking, 13.10

I'm using Ultimate Edition 3.5. There is an image below, hopefully it's clear enough. On the bottom right I created a new network (Ad-Hoc) with a WEP key. How do I connect it? Clicking on it or typing it in doesn't work. I'm using Ethernet on my laptop, but I tried also enabling Ad-Hoc on the laptop -- it doesn't do anything. On Ubuntu 13.10 it was quite simple, can't figure it out.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be doing everything right. I think it's a KDE issue, seeing as to how you're using Ultimate Edition 3.5. You can try running the **sudo apt-get update** command or update to U.E 3.6